# Unable to perform REST API call in CloudPages

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

I have been trying to do a HTTP Post for quite a while and I can't get it to work in CloudPages. The auth token call works, but not the other one. I am trying to create HTML emails in CloudPages. It works in POSTMAN. Here are the two methods I have tried:

```
var url = 'https://xxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets'

var payload = '{"name": "API Generated Email", "channels":{"email": true, "web": false}, "views":{"html":{"content": "<html><body></body></html>"}, "text":{}, "subjectline":{"content": "Test subject line"}, "preheader":{"content": "Test preheader"}}, "assetType":{"name": "htmlemail", "id": 208}}';

var auth = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;

  var req = new Script.Util.HttpRequest(url);
  req.emptyContentHandling = 0;
  req.retries = 2;
  req.continueOnError = true;
  req.contentType = "application/json"
  req.setHeader("Authorization", auth);
  req.method = "POST";
  req.postData = Stringify(payload);

  var resp = req.send();
```

and the 2nd one:

```
var url = "https://xxx.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets";
  var contentType = "application/json";
  var payload = '{"name": "API Generated Email", "channels":{"email": true, "web": false}, "views":{"html":{"content": "<html><body></body></html>"}, "text":{}, "subjectline":{"content": "Test subject line"}, "preheader":{"content": "Test preheader"}}, "assetType":{"name": "htmlemail", "id": 208}}';
  payload = Stringify(payload);
  var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
  var headerValues = [bear];
  var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload, headerNames, headerValues);
```

I am not getting any errors in my try/catch. But the email I am wanting to generate is not generating.
Neither of these work. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your payload is a string instead of an object.  Should be something like this:

```javascript
var payload = {
  "name": "API Generated Email",
  "channels": {
    "email": true,
    "web": false
  },
  "views": {
    "html": {
      "content": "<html><body></body></html>"
    },
    "text": {},
    "subjectline": {
      "content": "Test subject line"
    },
    "preheader": {
      "content": "Test preheader"
    }
  },
  "assetType": {
    "name": "htmlemail",
    "id": 208
  }
};
```

Your auth header value may need to be adjusted also.  Your code sample doesn't show where `bear` is set.

Here's a sample asset retrieve that I've used in CloudPage.  The create would be similar:

```javascript
if (accessToken != "") {

      var url = endPoint + "asset/v1/content/assets/query";
      var headerNames = ["Authorization"];
      var headerValues = ["Bearer " + accessToken];
      var contentType = 'application/json';
      var payload = {
        "query":  {
            "leftOperand": {
                "property": "data.email.legacy.legacyId",
                "simpleOperator": "equals",
                "value": Email_ID
            },
            "logicalOperator": "OR",
            "rightOperand": {
                "property": "legacyData.legacyId",
                "simpleOperator": "equals",
                "value": Email_ID
            }
        }
      };

      var assets = {};

      try {

          var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload), headerNames, headerValues);
          assets = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(result.Response[0]);


      } catch (e) {

        Write("<br>e", Stringify(e));

      }

}
```

Comment: Hello Adam. Thanks for the response! I did retrieve the token and that works as I did Write(bear); and it shows up. I did remove the quotes and now it works. Thanks!